# A program to proxy MDNS requests to the DNS server

Tags: haskell, networking, socket, server, proxy

I wrote a program to proxy MDNS requests in a local network to the DNS server. This is useful because in some private networks, host names ending in ".local" are configured in the DNS server. But ".local" is actually reversed for MDNS. Some systems have problems resolving these host names because they only try to resolve names through MDNS while those names are configured in the DNS server.

I started to use Haskell because XMonad. This is my first "practical" program written in Haskell. It would be very helpful if anyone could kindly give me some suggestions to improve my code.

The repository is here: https://github.com/abaw/mdns2dns

Here's the code for the main program:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DoAndIfThenElse #-}
import Control.Monad (forever,forM,guard,void)
import Control.Concurrent (forkIO)
import qualified Data.ByteString as B
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as BL
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as C
import Data.Binary.Get (getWord32host,runGet)
import Data.Char (isAscii)
import Data.Functor ((<$>))
import Data.Maybe (catMaybes)
import Debug.Trace (traceShow)
import Network.DNS
import Network.Multicast (addMembership)
import Network.Socket hiding (recv,sendTo)
import Network.Socket.ByteString(recv,sendTo)
import System.Environment (getArgs)
import System.Exit (exitFailure)

-- | The port used for MDNS requests/respones
mdnsPort :: PortNumber
mdnsPort = 5353

-- | The multicast IP address used for MDNS responses
mdnsIp :: HostAddress
mdnsIp = runGet getWord32host $ BL.pack [224,0,0,251]

-- | The SockAddr used for MDNS response
mdnsAddr :: SockAddr
mdnsAddr = SockAddrInet mdnsPort mdnsIp

-- | The maximum size of UDP DNS message defined in RFC-1035
maxDNSMsgSize :: Int
maxDNSMsgSize = 512

-- | Convert a String with only ascii characters to Domain
toDomain :: String -> Domain
toDomain = C.pack

-- | Convert strict ByteString to lazy ByteString
bsFromStrict :: B.ByteString -> BL.ByteString
bsFromStrict = BL.pack . B.unpack

-- | Convert lazy ByteString to strict ByteString
bsFromLazy :: BL.ByteString -> B.ByteString
bsFromLazy = B.concat . BL.toChunks

-- | Create a MDNS response
responseMDNS :: DNSFormat        -- ^ The original MDNS request
     -> [ResourceRecord] -- ^ The answers to response
     -> DNSFormat        -- ^ The result MDNS response
responseMDNS req answers = DNSFormat h [] answers [] []
  where
h = DNSHeader { identifier = identifier (header req)
          , flags = (flags $ header req) {qOrR = QR_Response}
          , qdCount = 0
          , anCount = length answers
          , nsCount = 0
          , arCount = 0
          }

-- | Query DNS for a list of qustions
lookupDNS :: Resolver            -- ^ The resolver to lookup with
      -> [Question]          -- ^ The list of questions to look up
      -> IO [ResourceRecord] -- ^ The answers
lookupDNS resolver questions = concat <$> forM questions lookup'
  where
lookup' :: Question -> IO [ResourceRecord]
-- returns [] if no results found
lookup' q = maybe [] answer <$> lookupRaw resolver (qname q) (qtype q)

-- | Proxy MDNS queries for domains ending with the given suffixes.
proxyForSuffixes :: [Domain] -> IO ()
proxyForSuffixes suffixes = withSocketsDo $ do
seed <- makeResolvSeed defaultResolvConf
sock <- socket AF_INET Datagram defaultProtocol
-- We should work properly when other MDNS server(e.g. avahi-daemon) is
-- running, so we need to set ReuseAddr socket option.
setSocketOption sock ReuseAddr 1
bind sock serverAddr
mdnsIpStr <- inet_ntoa mdnsIp
addMembership sock mdnsIpStr
forever $ tryReceivingMsg sock seed
  where
serverAddr = SockAddrInet mdnsPort 0
tryReceivingMsg sock seed = do
    bytes <- recv sock maxDNSMsgSize
    case decode (bsFromStrict bytes) of
    Left err -> putStrLn $ "received a invalid message:" ++ err
    Right msg' -> processMsg sock seed msg'
processMsg sock seed msg =  proxyIt
  where
    proxyIt
    | notRequest || null questionToUs = return ()
    | otherwise =  do
          putStrLn $ "will handle:" ++ show questionToUs
          void $ forkIO $ withResolver seed $ \resolver -> do
          answers <- lookupDNS resolver questionToUs
          let rsp = responseMDNS msg answers
          void $ sendTo sock (msgToByteString rsp) mdnsAddr
    questionToUs = [ q | q <- question msg
               , qtype q == A
               , any (`C.isSuffixOf` qname q) suffixes]
    notRequest = qOrR (flags $ header msg) /= QR_Query
    -- encode the response and then convert it to strict ByteString from a
    -- lazy one.
    msgToByteString = bsFromLazy . encode

main = do
suffixes <- getArgs
if all (all isAscii) suffixes
then proxyForSuffixes $ map (toDomain . fixSuffix) suffixes
else putStrLn "Only supports domain names in ascii!!" >> exitFailure
  where
-- names in DNS questions should end in "."
fixSuffix suffix
    | last suffix == '.' = suffix
    | otherwise = suffix ++ "."
```

I was particularly wondering if there is a better way to write:

```
mdnsIp = runGet getWord32host $ BL.pack [224,0,0,251]
```

Answer (score 2):

Overall this code reads well. Nice job.

I do not know a better way to write `mdnsIp`.

I have two concerns:

1. Logging. A proper daemon should have logging to let people know what is happening.
2. Infinite loops. There are several places in the code where the service could just spin for an indeterminate amount of time. The usual solution to this is a timeout of some sort.